# Turtle is not running

Tags: python-3.x, function, python-turtle, line-endings

```py
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.right(100)
t.done()
```

That is my code, but there is no result after run. Why this problem is arising and what can I do now?

Comment: Please provide more context.

Answer (score 0):

> t.right(100)

this rotates the turtle by 100 degrees

> t.done()

is not a function. All your code is doing essentially is creating a canvas and putting nothing on it. From here, you would need to know about t.pendown() and other functions to make it work this [link](https://realpython.com/beginners-guide-python-turtle/) will be helpful in getting started with the python turtle.